# Make pycharm keymap same as Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, pycharm

I am using macbook. For some reason the keymap of pycharm is different than the Android Studio keymap. Is there a way to make PyCharm the same as Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! Preferences -> Keymap -> on the combobox change

> Mac OS X

to

> Mac OS X 10.5+